# Write a recursive function that takes a positive integer n and plots an N-by-N Hadamard pattern where N = 2^n

Tags: java, beginner, recursion

This is web exercise 2.3.20. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Write a recursive program  that takes a command-line argument n and
> plots an N-by-N Hadamard pattern where N = 2^n. Do not use an array. A
> 1-by-1 Hadamard pattern is a single black square. In general a
> 2N-by-2N Hadamard pattern is obtained by aligning 4 copies of the
> N-by-N pattern in the form of a 2-by-2 grid, and then inverting the
> colors of all the squares in the lower right N-by-N copy. The N-by-N
> Hadamard H(N) matrix is a boolean matrix with the remarkable property
> that any two rows differ in exactly N/2 bits. Here are the first few
> Hadamard matrices.
>
> [image]

Here is my program:

```
public class wexercise2_3_20 
{
    public static void hadamard(int n, double x, double y, double size,
                                boolean color)
    {
        double x1 = x - size/2, x2 = x + size/2;
        double y1 = y - size/2, y2 = y + size/2;
        if (n == 0) return;
        if (color) 
        {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x,y,size);
        }
        else
        {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
            StdDraw.filledSquare(x,y,size);
        }
        hadamard(n-1, x1, y1, size/2, color);
        hadamard(n-1, x1, y2, size/2, color);
        hadamard(n-1, x2, y2, size/2, color);
        hadamard(n-1, x2, y1, size/2, !color);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        hadamard(n, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, true);
    }
}
```

[StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book.

Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I would put the `if (n == 0) return;` at the beginning.

Comment: @MiguelAvila May I ask why?

Comment: Because even if it is a bit, it saves four operations (the initialization of `x1, x2, y1, y2`).

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `double` arguments for your function ? Because it seems me you have a matrix N x N where N is a power of 2.

Comment: @dariosicily I understand. But I think this is because of the StdDraw library. It creates a 1.0 by 1.0 square and only accepts double values.

Comment: I thought about this but if you pass ints to StdDraw they will automatically converted to doubles.

Comment: Yes but in that case you should manually scale the drawing window to fit those bigger than 1.0 integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code is present the following exit condition :

```
if (n == 0) return;
```

You can rewrite your code executing it just when `n > 0` starting from the assumption that `n` is always positive from the problem description, so your function can be rewritten like below :

```
public static void hadamard(int n, double x, double y, double size,
                                boolean color) {
    if (n > 0) { 
     //your code 
    }
}
```

***Note***: as @RoToRa noticed in his comment below my answer, wrapping the full code function in a `if` branch is not a good practice code, so better to use the old `if (n == 0) return;` at the beginning of the function followed by the body of the function.

At the beginning of the code there are the following declarations:

```
double x1 = x - size/2, x2 = x + size/2;
double y1 = y - size/2, y2 = y + size/2;
```

You can rewrite them like below:

```
final halfSize = size / 2;
final double x1 = x - halfSize;
final double y1 = y - halfSize;
```

Then the recursive calls to your function can be rewritten like below:

```
--n; //<-- decrementing n here for clarity
hadamard(n, x1, y1, halfSize, color);
hadamard(n, x1, y1 + size, halfSize, color);
hadamard(n, x1 + size, y1 + size, halfSize, color);
hadamard(n, x1 + size, y1, halfSize, !color);
```

Your method can be rewritten like this:

```
public static void hadamard(int n, double x, double y, double size,
            boolean color) {

    if (n > 0) {

        final double halfSize = size / 2;
        final double x1 = x - halfSize;
        final double y1 = y - halfSize;
        Color c = color ? StdDraw.BLACK : StdDraw.WHITE;

        StdDraw.setPenColor(c);
        StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, size);

        --n; //put here for clarity
        hadamard(n, x1, y1, halfSize, color);
        hadamard(n, x1, y1 + size, halfSize, color);
        hadamard(n, x1 + size, y1 + size, halfSize, color);
        hadamard(n, x1 + size, y1, halfSize, !color);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. :)

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh You are welcome.

Comment: Generally an early return as in the original code is prefered over wrapping the whole function in an `if` block. See for example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Comment: @RoToRa Probably I was too greedy to write less code lines, rethinking about it although there is no return value it is more readable the code with  the old check `if (n == 0) return` at the beginning of the code. I will add a note with a reference to your comment, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Class names in Java should start with a capital letter.

Avoid initializing two variables in the same line.

The `filledSquare` call is the same in the two `if` branches, it could be moved out of the `if`.  Now the two `if` branches only change in the argument to the `setPenColor` call, and you could replace it by

```
Color theColor = color ? WHITE : BLACK;
```

Now it seems like you could drop the boolean argument altogether (boolean arguments suck) and pass a Color; all you need is a function that inverts the color.

This criticism has nothing to do with recursion; I have no idea if this works correctly or not :)